# Delete new row inserted with bindingsource.addnew()

Tags: c#

I used the BindingSource.AddNew() to add a row in my DataGridView, but if the row is empty i need to remove it. The same happens when i add new a row with down arrow of keyboard but automatic way.

how to do it when used command AddNew() ?

thanks.

Comment: you could subscribe to the `bindingsource.ListChanged` event and get rid of any empties, or any entries that do not meet your criterias.

Comment: @blaze_125 I tested it but it does not differentiate the down arrow event or the AddNew ()